# Proving That $\sum^{n}_{k=0} \bigl(\frac{4}{5}\bigr)^k < 5$

Tags: summation, induction

> Using induction, prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \biggl(\frac 4 5 \biggr)^k = 1+\frac{4}{5}+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^3+\cdots +\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^n<5$$ for all natural numbers $n.$

What I have tried is as follows.

Consider the statement $$P(n):1+\frac{4}{5}+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^2+\cdots +\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^n<5.$$

For $n=1$, we have that $\displaystyle P(1):1+\frac{4}{5}<5$ is true.

For $n=k$, we assume that $$\displaystyle P(k):1+\frac{4}{5}+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^2+\cdots +\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^k<5.$$

$\displaystyle P(k+1):1+\frac{4}{5}+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^2+\cdots +\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^k+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^{k+1}<5+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^{k+1}$

How can I prove that the sum on the left is $< 5?$ Help me please. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it should be $\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{k=0}\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^{k}<5$ instead of $\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{k=0}\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^{n}<5$

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^n r^n = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1 - r}$ for $|r| < 1?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume
$$
1+\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k < 5
$$
for some positive integer $k$.$\;$Then
\begin{align*}
&
\frac{4}{5}
{\,\cdot}
\left(
1+\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k
\right) < \frac{4}{5}{\,\cdot\,}5
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^3+\cdots +\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k+1} < 4
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1+\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k+1} < 5
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the induction.

Answer (score 3):

$$1+\frac{4}{5}+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^3+\cdots +\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^n = 5\left(1-\dfrac{4^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}} \right)$$

Comment: I understand you talk about formula and I am agree, sorry for haste and thanks, but what is RHS?

Comment: RHS is a common acronym for "Right Hand Side". Similarly, LHS is an acronym for "Left Hand Side".

Comment: Corrected. This haste weights $-1$, so it is anti gravitation.

Comment: Note I didn't downvote, and you can't be sure if it was for the small mistake or for some other reason, but it seems who ever did has now retracted that, and you've now also got an upvote as well.

Comment: You had all rights, it was my fault. Same for somebody other. I can be only grateful for both - who shows us our mistakes, takes care of us.